# Suggestion for better icon separation in markdown editor

Tags: feature-request, design, editor

I think it'd be useful to split the Hyperlink, BlockQuote, CodeSample, and Image actions/icons into 2 groups that are organized closer to their functionality as the other buttons are arranged.

**`B`** *`I`* | `Link` `Image` | `CodeSample` `BlockQuote` | `OrderedList`.....

I often find myself hunting for the code sample button since the context of its position is confusing being positioned between Link/Image along with a similar block quote also being wedged in there.

Comment: Hover the images to show their tooltip once, and remember their keyboard shortcuts ;-)

Comment: @Arjan I know, I also find ctrl+K to be the most worthless keyboard shortcut ever. One of the very first things I always do with visual studio is remap out every ctrl+K shortcut they have to the left side of the keyboard.